# QR code send to Activity or Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, qr-code

I would like to have a small database with some QR codes for specific products. Then, I would like to build an Android app with a QR scanner that could scan the code and open an activity that has many information on that specific code.

I found a [ZXing QR Scanner](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-qr-code-scanner-using-zxingscanner-library-tutorial/) which is easy to implement (see below), but I have no idea how to make it scan only known codes. Also, I don't know how to generate a QR code that would be connected to any activity.

I don't know if I made myself clear and if I'm dreaming of flying horses, but it would be great if you could help me with this. I would appreciate very much!

Comment: Not the best question to ask on Stack Overflow since we are not solving a code related issue... I think there are number of barcode API (Search it on ProgrammableWeb) and make your app work with them first. Once worked, create your own database  and make calls to your database instead other API. Countless tutorials are available on how to achieve your desired result

Comment: What do you mean by this -> "Also, I don't know how to generate a QR code that would be connected to any activity?". Explain a bit, other stuff is easy and DIY. And at last, a pro tip - use [Mobile Vision API](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision) (A modified version of [official Google Vision API](https://github.com/KingsMentor/MobileVisionBarcodeScanner) just to skip the boilerplate code) for faster scanning.

Comment: I mean Generate a Code that will be associated with some text on an activity. I can generate codes online with text or URL's (e.g. http://goqr.me/), but they have only a text format. I would like to generate a code that would send me to a specific Activity in an Android app. See it as a replacement for an URL that sends me directly to the activity

Comment: Also, it would be nice if it could work only on the codes I am generating, not widely available to all the codes generated online

Comment: Store Strings in your database, compare it with the string value of scanned barcode and if matched, pass it to next activity and show it's related information. For generating QR code use [this](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen) Library.

Comment: Thanks. I will try an implement the code generator and store the strings. I hope it's not that difficult, as I'm a noob, as you can see.

Comment: Thank you, @LalitSinghFauzdar!